# Best solution/package for fuzzy searching collections?

Tags: meteor

Can anyone point me in the right direction to a good fuzzy search solution or package? I want to be able to search through a couple collections, including Meteor.users.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is https://atmospherejs.com/perak/fuzzy-search which uses the [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm. An example taken from the readme:

```
// If we have a collection named "Drinks" which contains "beer", "juice" and "milk"

var searchString = "bear"; // user typed "bear" instead of "beer"

// search "Drinks" collection for string "bear"
var someCursor = Drinks.find({ drink_name: searchString });

// "bear" is not found, so we want to find most similar word to give user suggestion (Did you mean...)
if(someCursor.count() == 0)
{
    // expose entire collection
    var tempCursor = Drinks.find({ }, { drink_name: true });

    // find most similar string
    var bestWord = mostSimilarString(tempCursor, "drink_name", searchString, -1, false);

    // in this example, bestWord is "beer", show user a suggestion: "Did you mean beer?"
    // ...
}
```

There are also other alternatives such as https://atmospherejs.com/matteodem/easy-search which uses [Elastic Search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) and https://github.com/Crenshinibon/spomet which is also very powerful but may look harder to use at first.

Comment: Hey, could you please add syntax highlighting to your code?
Just add js behind the start of your codeblock.

Like this:\`\`\`js // your code here \`\`\`